# How to compile GoogleTest tests efficiently in separate subdirectory in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I have a problem in understanding, how to efficiently introduce tests into a project. I have code, which is compiled to `ProjectMain` executable, and I want to write tests for it (which compile to `ProjectTest` executable). I would like to keep the tests separate from the code of the `ProjectMain`, so the file structure is the following:

```
Project
  include
    foo_class.h
  src
    foo_class.cpp
    main.cpp
  test
    include
    src
      foo_class_test.cpp
      <"gtest_main" is used, so no "main.cpp" here>
    CMakeLists.txt
  CMakeLists.txt
```

How do I relate those two `CMakeLists.txt` with each other, so that **EVERY** source file is compiled exactly once (when both `ProjectMain` and `ProjectTest` are built)? More precisely, what is the best way to let `ProjectTest` know about `foo_class` implementation?

I could add `ProjectMain`'s sources to `ProjectTest` target, but that will basically mean recompilation of `ProjectMain`. The better choice would be to split the latter into two parts: a library, which takes all the codebase of it, and a dummy executable with `main` function only. Then `ProjectTest` would just link to the library, but I'd prefer to build `ProjectMain` into a single file (executable only).

So are there other alternatives? Or maybe I miss something? Maybe I can point somehow to CMake that `ProjectTest` needs `ProjectMain`'s sources?

Comment: The better choice is the best choice.

Comment: @master_clown Just use a static library? Any functionality required by the tests/the executable will become part of the executables,no deployment of the lib necessary. Any attempts to improve linking performance is probably premature optimization: It's likely that the combined link time improvements for all builds ever done for the project is less than the time it takes to implement this kind of optimization.

Comment: @fabian, thank you! That came to my mind, but I thought that people usually get by somehow different.

Answer (score 2):

Check out CMake's [Object Libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries)

I have personally never used them (I personally use the approach you mentioned with a library and an executable with just a `main` function) but I think this is what you are looking for. Basically just compile source files into objects for linking later.

Comment: Thank you! This is a good idea. However, the linkage stage will all the same repeat twice for all `ProjectMain`'s sources. I can't say whether it's bad or not, because I'm not sure, what takes more time: compilation or linkage.

By the way, we also can combine your idea with @casaDePapel solution (which assumes adding only common sources to both targets).

Comment: I think the only way for it to link only once is if the object files are first linked as a library. Then you only have the two executables link with the already linked lib ? I might be wrong though.

Comment: I agree. I'd still wish to avoid splitting into a library and an executable, though. But seems like this is the only efficient way

Comment: If build speed is an issue, I heavily recommend using `ccache` if you're on Linux. Basically a system-wide compilation cache, and very easy to integrate with an existing CMake project. 

Just install it through apt, then use a small cmake module such as this one https://github.com/NicolasIRAGNE/CMakeScripts/blob/main/ccache.cmake and you're ready to go.

Edit: this is not really related to your question but it really made my life better so figured i'd share

Comment: Thanks! Never heard of it, but definitely will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

in your cmakelists.txt you may define 2 executables:
`add_executable(ProjectMain ${COMMON_SRC} ${ProjectMain_SRC} ) add_executable(ProjectTest ${COMMON_SRC} ${ProjectTest_SRC} )` 
with ProjectMain_SRC and ProjectTest_SRC to be defines before like this:

`list(APPEND ProjectMain_SRC  file_1 file_2 ...)`

COMMON_SRC list contains files used by both of executables

Comment: Thank you! I thought about it too, but sometimes it may proof difficult to gather all common sources. Dependencies in code may be arbitrary: the class you want to test may include many more other classes, and we will need to include their implementation too. Though it may be easy if the sources are separated like this from the start, but I'm not sure